# salesforce .net toolkit relationship query serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, salesforce

I created strongly type classes to use when using the toolkit to query salesforce

```
public class SFAccount
{        
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Account_Code__c { get; set; }
}

QueryResult<SFAccount> results = await _client.QueryAsync<SFAccount>(@"SELECT Id,
                                                                     Name,
                                                                     Account_Code__c
                                                                     FROM Account
                                                                     ORDER BY Id ASC");
```

This works fine as expected.
But when the query includes relationship columns using __r, I can't seem to get the toolkit to serialize  my data to class object

```
public class SFLocation
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Account__c { get; set; }
    public string Account__r_Name { get; set; }
    public string Account__r_Account_Code__c { get; set; }           
}

QueryResult<SFLocation> results = await _client.QueryAsync<SFLocation>(@"SELECT Id,
                                                                Name,
                                                                Account__c,
                                                                Account__r.Name,
                                                                Account__r.Account_Code__c,
                                                                FROM Location__c
                                                                ORDER BY Id ASC");
```

The last two properties (Account__r_Name and Account__r_Account_Code__c) are not being populated and my query is valid and returns data

How would I construct my class so that the toolkit would be able to serialize the result data to the class?

Comment: response from wade wegner "One trick I use is to use the "dynamic" type, then run Fiddler in the background. Take the JSON result from the query and then plug it into http://json2csharp.com/ - it will model the class for you. Hope that helps!"
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/10/nothing-but-dotnet-querying-objects-new-force-com-toolkit-net.html#comment-1699465283